# inf-ruby eval current line

Tags: ruby, emacs, elisp

[inf-ruby](https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby) supports `ruby-send-region`, which combined with marker-fu can evaluate a single line, but I'd prefer to have a function like `ruby-send-line` to eval the cursor's current line in one keystroke. Does this exist? If not, how can I begin to make it?

Answer (score 2):

The following appears to work reasonably well:

```
(defun ruby-send-line ()
  "Send the current line to the inferior Ruby process."
  (interactive)
  (ruby-send-region (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))
```